# symfony: logical operations inside config.yml?

Tags: symfony, yaml

is it possible to make logical operations inside the `config.yml` file?

For example I tried this:

```
width: 50
height: 30
width_more_height: %width% + %height%
```

but I get an error..

Comment: I would be surprised if this was part of YAML's spec, so I'd imagine not.

Comment: do the addition in your code? Configuration should not have logic, your code should use configuration to implement logic

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it the way you wrote inside .yml file. But there is a way to get the idea to work. You can do it inside your bundle extension file inside DependencyInjection folder. If you can, move the width and height parameters to bundle, maybe make a CoreBundle or something.

```
class MyExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');

        $sum = $container->getParameter('width') + $container->getParameter('height');
        $container->setParameter('width_more_height', $sum);
    }
}
```